# Uneven space above and below listing with parskip used

Tags: listings, parskip

The following code creates a bigger space below the listing. I need `parskip` to keep space between paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parskip}{6pt} % this is the culprit

\lstnewenvironment{codesample}
{\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}}}
{}

\begin{document}

Then load the file into your web browser using a some URL
like this one:

\begin{codesample}
    file:///Users/username/javascript/hello.html
\end{codesample}

Open the developer tools window to see the greeting in the console.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\showoutput` shows the ⟨dimen⟩ part of `\parskip` twice below the environment, plus a slightly different `\baselineskip` on each side. `\lstnewenvironment{codesample}
{\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}}}
{\vspace{-\parskip}}` seems to help.

Comment: @frougon You may want to form it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: All right, done. :- )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\showoutput`, for instance before `\begin{document}`, one can see the following material set in vertical mode, around your verbatim text:

```latex
...\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 1.6556
...\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x345.0, glue set 56.99707fil

(...)   <--- verbatim text here

...\penalty -50
...\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0
...\glue 0.0
...\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
...\glue(\parskip) 6.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 1.45552
```

The first glue item has the natural length of your `\parskip`, i.e. `6pt`. Then `\parskip` gets temporarily modified (as shown by `\glue(\parskip) 0.0`), one `\baselineskip` glue item of `1.6556pt` is appended, then comes the verbatim material, after it **two** glue items whose natural length is that of your `\parskip` (i.e., `6pt`, and you can see your `\parskip` gets restored), and finally one `\baselineskip` glue item of `1.45552pt`.

The two slightly different lengths of the “before” and “after” `\baselineskip`s are most probably due to the different fonts in use: I'd say that the “before” `\baselineskip` comes from the font of the main text, while the “after” `\baselineskip` comes from the font used for the verbatim text.

However, these two `\baselineskip`s are close enough that their difference is not really noticeable.
So, if we cancel one of the two `6pt` high globs of glue that follow the verbatim text, it will be surrounded by almost-equal vertical spaces from above and below. This can be done using this definition for your `codesample` environment (I don't claim there is no better way):

```latex
\lstnewenvironment{codesample}
  {\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}}}
  {\vspace{-\parskip}}
```

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parskip}{6pt} % this is the culprit

\lstnewenvironment{codesample}
  {\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}}}
  {\vspace{-\parskip}}

\begin{document}

Then load the file into your web browser using a some URL
like this one:

\begin{codesample}
    file:///Users/username/javascript/hello.html
\end{codesample}

Open the developer tools window to see the greeting in the console.

\end{document}
```

[image]